# Making a default in a DropDownListFor when displaying from a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I make a blank default to be displayed like " " in this @Html.DropDownListFor.

I have tried the over-rides and they don't work for this.

HTML:

```
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalsDDL, Model.TerminalsDDL, new { id = "ddlTerminalID", @class = "form-control align-middle" })</td>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = TCBL.GetTerminalData();
        return View(model);
    }

    //POST: TerminalCommand/Index
    /*This function will insert a user selecter terminal command into the TerminalCommand table*/
    public ActionResult AddTerminalCommand(AddTerminalCommandVM input)
    {

        TerminalCommand terminalCommand = new TerminalCommand();
        terminalCommand.TerminalID = input.TerminalID;
        terminalCommand.Command = input.CommandID;
        terminalCommand.CommandValue = input.CommandValue;

        TCBL.AddTerminalCommand(terminalCommand);

        var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "TerminalCommand");
        return Json(new { Url = redirectUrl });
    }
```

Data Layer:

```
 /*Gets All termianls for the terminalsDDL and all terminal Cmds for Model.TerminalCommands*/
    public TerminalCommandVM GetTerminalData()
    {
        TerminalCommandVM terminals = new TerminalCommandVM();

        //For Terminal drop downs
        terminals.TerminalsDDL = TCDA.GetTerminalsDropDown();

        //For terminal cmd lists 
        terminals.TerminalCommands = TCDA.GetAll();

        //For helpdescription
        terminals.HelpDescriptions = TCDA.GetAllHelpDescriptionValues();
        terminals.HelpDescriptionID = TCDA.GetAllHelpDescriptionIDs();

        //For TerminalCommandLookupsDDL
        List<SelectListItem> terminalCommandLookups = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var terminalCommandLookupsResults = TCDA.GetAllTerminalCommandLookups().OrderBy(o => o.Name); //.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("S3"));

        if (terminalCommandLookupsResults != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in terminalCommandLookupsResults)
            {
                SelectListItem newItem = new SelectListItem();
                newItem.Text = item.Name;
                newItem.Value = item.ID.ToString();
                terminalCommandLookups.Add(newItem);
            }
        }

        var terminalCommandValues = TCDA.GetAllTerminalCommandValues();
        terminals.TerminalCommandValues = terminalCommandValues;

        terminals.TerminalCommandLookupsDDL = terminalCommandLookups;

        return terminals;
    }
```

Bottom is data access layer, where the CA gets the data for display. I believe HTML should have some sort of default blank selection though..

Comment: please at least show the controller code where your building the `TerminalsDDL` along with the viewmodel

Comment: @GregH Sure, I will update the OP

Comment: The code you've updated doesnt really help us at all as everything of importance is hidden in the method `GetTerminalData` (and the viewmodel still isnt posted). :)

Comment: @GregH My apologies. Sorry it's been a long day.

Comment: no worries- im going to gracefully bow out sorry mate. the code you want to be looking at is further buried inside the `GetTerminalsDropDown` method which isnt shown in the newest update of the question (and your viewmodel still isnt posted). good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a blank default before the for loop in your Data Layer

```
SelectListItem newItem = new SelectListItem();
newItem.Text = "";
newItem.Value = "";
terminalCommandLookups.Add(newItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this overload of Dropdownlistfor -

```
Html.DropDownListFor(Expression<Func<dynamic,TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectLestItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
```

like this

```
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.TerminalsDDL, Model.TerminalsDDL,"", new { id = "ddlTerminalID", @class = "form-control align-middle" })</td>
```